# Spring Security OAuth2 for iOS App

Tags: ios, oauth, spring-security, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application that will provide a web app and a REST interface for an iOS application that a colleague develops.

The Spring Boot MVC web application already uses Spring Security with a form based login and a JPA entity for authentication of users with roles. Everything pretty straightforward.

We want to use OAuth2 for connecting the iOS app to the server for accessing the REST API so that we do not have to store the username/password on the device.

What would be the easiest configuration for this?

Do we need to call /oauth/authorize or would it be enough to call /oauth/token to get an access and a refresh token by sending the username/password the user provides once in a form in the iOS app?

I want the iOS application to be authenticated as the user via oauth token afterwards so that it can access the entities assigned to the user.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? Do you mind share your solution.